# What is the best library for reliably dealing with attachments from email?

Tags: php, python, perl, parsing, email

I have an application and need to write a program that is able to figure out attachments from all kinds of email senders (and MUAs) reliably.  PHP doesn't seem to have a great MIME parser so I was hoping some other languages might.

I've seen the [PHP Mail Mime Parser](http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/source/browse/trunk/MimeMailParser.class.php) but it's not robust at all and I know (and have confirmed) it doesn't work reliably with all MUAs.

Does anyone know of a more real-world-hardened mail parsing library?

I can use any language, doesn't matter.

Comment: That last sentence makes me want to write a MIME parser in LOLCODE.

Comment: @David: LOLCODE is for n00bs. I present to you the glory that is... Befunge (http://catseye.tc/projects/befunge93/doc/befunge93.html). I cower in fear of anyone implementing anything in it, ever.

Comment: @katrielalex:  I may be crazy, but I'm not that crazy.  LOLCODE, Intercal, whatever, I can be tempted by.  Not Befunge or COBOL.

Answer (score 4):

How about Perl 5's [Email::MIME](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::MIME)? Looks like something that will fulfill Your needs, if I understood You correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Python's [`email`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html) module is excellent and includes full support for MIME emails, including incremental parsing. I think the moral here is that you can do this in many languages.

Of course, you *should* do it in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Perl has [several email parsing libraries](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=MIME&mode=all), choose the one which suits your needs best.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of success using Ruby and the mail gem at http://github.com/mikel/mail this is now the default creator/parser for Rails.

I think you are really going to get answers from people with their preference of language so I think its ultimately a question of preference but we use this gem in the web front end of CloudMailin.